# How to list JBoss AS 7 datasource properties in Java code?

Tags: datasource, jboss7.x

I'm running JBoss AS 7.1.0.CR1b. I've got several datasources defined in my standalone.xml e.g.

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/MyDS" pool-name="MyDS_Pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>some-url</connection-url>
                    <driver>the-driver</driver>
                    [etc]
```

Everything works fine.

I'm trying to access the information contained here within my code - specifically the `connection-url` and `driver` properties.

I've tried getting the Datasource from JNDI, as normal, but it doesn't appear to provide access to these properties:

```
// catches removed
InitialContext context;
DataSource dataSource = null;
context = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup(jndi);
```

ClientInfo and DatabaseMetadata from a Connection object from this Datasource also don't contain these granular, JBoss properties either.

My code will be running inside the container with the datasource specfied, so all should be available. I've looked at the IronJacamar interface `org.jboss.jca.common.api.metadata.ds.DataSource`, and its implementing class, and these seem to have accessible hooks to the information I require, but I can't find any information on how to create such objects with these already deployed resources within the container (only constructor on impl involves inputting all properties manually).

JBoss AS 7's Command-Line Interface allows you to navigate and list the datasources as a directory system. http://www.paykin.info/java/add-datasource-programaticaly-cli-jboss-7/ provides an excellent post on how to use what I believe is the Java Management API to interact with the subsystem, but this appears to involve connecting to the target JBoss server. My code is already running *within* that server, so surely there must be an easier way to do this?

Hope somebody can help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're really trying to do is a management action. The best way to is to use the management API's that are available.

Here is a simple standalone example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final List<ModelNode> dataSources = getDataSources();
        for (ModelNode dataSource : dataSources) {
            System.out.printf("Datasource: %s%n", dataSource.asString());
        }
    }

    public static List<ModelNode> getDataSources() throws IOException {
        final ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
        request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set("read-resource");
        request.get("recursive").set(true);
        request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem", "datasources");
        ModelControllerClient client = null;
        try {
            client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9999);
            final ModelNode response = client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build());
            reportFailure(response);
            return response.get(ClientConstants.RESULT).get("data-source").asList();
        } finally {
            safeClose(client);
        }
    }

    public static void safeClose(final Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable != null) try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // no-op
        }
    }


    private static void reportFailure(final ModelNode node) {
        if (!node.get(ClientConstants.OUTCOME).asString().equals(ClientConstants.SUCCESS)) {
            final String msg;
            if (node.hasDefined(ClientConstants.FAILURE_DESCRIPTION)) {
                if (node.hasDefined(ClientConstants.OP)) {
                    msg = String.format("Operation '%s' at address '%s' failed: %s", node.get(ClientConstants.OP), node.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR), node.get(ClientConstants.FAILURE_DESCRIPTION));
                } else {
                    msg = String.format("Operation failed: %s", node.get(ClientConstants.FAILURE_DESCRIPTION));
                }
            } else {
                msg = String.format("Operation failed: %s", node);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The only other way I can think of is to add module that relies on servers internals. It could be done, but I would probably use the management API first.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JamesR.Perkins, looks good - thanks for taking the time to write it up. The fact we have to create the Client using `InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9999)` suggests that it involves some sort of external call to the server though, if you see what I mean, when we're already *running* in that environment. Was hoping I could inject an instance of some JBoss class to get at the subsystem/datasource properties without an explicit external call. If not, though, I'll certainly use your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenKirby AFAIK there is nothing that could be injected. It's really a management operation which is why it needs the client and the remote style connection. If I find anything else that would work or come up with something else I'll edit the answer. :-)

Comment: Found the JBoss CLI public API [https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7Command-linePublicAPI](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7Command-linePublicAPI), which _appears_ not to need the remote connection, but I can't currently upgrade to the JBoss version they recommend ("Since JBoss AS 7.1.1") . So have gone with your solution - thanks again for responding.

Comment: This works, but isn't there a simpler, more standardized way to do this?