# How to Use a dynamic @PersistenceContext with Hibernate and JBoss AS 7 Connection Pool

Tags: hibernate, persistence, jboss7.x, entitymanager

Good morning, I'm trying to make a database script executor.

When the web application starts, will show to the User, a listing of available datasources (pre-registered in JBoss AS7).

After choosing the desired datasource, the application will use a @PersistenceContext based on the choice that the User did.

The answer that says how to list the datasources I found here:
[James R. Perkins - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706511/1703546)

And the answer that tells how to create EntityManagers from a JNDI I found here:
[Nayan Wadekar - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295515)

My question is. It is possible to define a @PersistenceContext from a JNDI?
How would my "persistence.xml" file, if I do not use a JTA DataSource ("jta-data-source") declared?

Currently it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="database" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Is there any tutorial or source code example that explains a little how this operation work?

Note: I want to control the JBoss AS Connection Pools, I would not schedule it, I believe that JBoss will better manage Pools than any code I create.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution if all of your datasources connects to one database using different database schemas. In this case you can create one data source, define it in persistence.xml and dynamically create EntityManagerFactory based on this datasource but for another database scheme:

```
private Map<String, EntityManagerFactory> entityManagers = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, EntityManagerFactory>());

public EntityManager getEntityManager(String databaseSchema) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = entityManagers.get(databaseSchema.toUpperCase());
    if (emf == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("your_persistent_unit_name", createMap(databaseSchema));
        entityManagers.put(databaseSchema, emf);
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public static java.util.Map createMap(String databaseSchema) {
    java.util.Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("provider", "org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence");
    map.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider");
    map.put("hibernate.default_schema", databaseSchema.toUpperCase());
    map.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    map.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
    map.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform");
    map.put("hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name", databaseSchema+ "_entity_manager");
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Hello

Thanks for your reply, will be very useful in cases where it is used the same database with different schemas.

But if I use different databases, I could instantiate my persistenceUnit, and change the value of the jta-data-source?
Or, possibly, I could create a persistenceUnit in code without using xml?

Comment: Daniel, it seems there is no way to do this only in code, but you can try to create temporary *-ds.xml as described at [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/73156) and put that xml to ... don't know where exactly in JB7, but guys said "After much complaining by the community, JBoss actually does support deployable data sources again (-ds.xml)" at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339736/how-to-dynamically-add-datasources-to-jboss-7[/link)